# Confusing step in the proof of convergence of Expected Sarsa

Tags: proof-explanation

The proof of convergence of Expected Sarsa is presented in [A Theoretical & Empirical Analysis of Expected Sarsa](https://hadovanhasselt.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/a_theoretical_and_empirical_analysis_of_expected_sarsa.pdf). This proof is similar to the proof of convergence of Sarsa, presented in [Convergence Results for Single-Step On-Policy Reinforcement-Learning Algorithms](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~szepesva/papers/singh98convergence.pdf).

In both proofs, the authors rely on the following lemma, reproduced here for clarity:

#### Lemma 1

Consider a stochastic process $(\zeta_t, \Delta_t, F_t)$, where $\zeta_t, \Delta_t, F_t : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the equations

$$
\Delta_{t+1}(x_t) = (1-\zeta_t(x_t))\Delta_t(x_t)+\zeta_t(x_t)F_t(x_t),
$$

where $x_t \in X$ and $t=0, 1, 2, \ldots$. Let $P_t$ be a sequence of increasing $\sigma$-fields ($\sigma$-algebras) such that $\zeta_0$ and $\Delta_0$ are $P_0$-measurable and $\zeta_t$, $\Delta_t$, and $F_{t-1}$ are $P_t$-measurable, with $t\ge 1$. Assume that the following hold:

1. The $\mathcal{X}$ set is finite,
2. $\zeta_t(x_t) \in [0, 1]$, $\sum_t \zeta_t(x_t) = \infty, \sum_t(\zeta_t(x_t))^2<\infty$ with probability one and $\forall x \neq x_t : \zeta_t(x) = 0$,
3. $\|\mathbb{E}\{F_t|P_t\| \le \kappa\|\Delta_t\| + c_t$, where $\kappa \in [0, 1)$ and $c_t$ converges to zero with probability one,
4. $\mathrm{Var}\{F_t(x_t)|P_t\} \le K(1+\kappa\|\Delta_t\|)^2$, where $K$ is some constant,

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes a maximum norm. Then, $\Delta_t$ converges to zero with probability one.

#### The proof

The authors then go on to apply Lemma 1 with $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{A}$ ($\mathcal{S}$ are the states, $\mathcal{A}$ are the actions), $P_t = \{Q_0, s_0, a_0, r_0, \alpha_0, s_1, a_1, \ldots, s_t, a_t\}$, $x_t=(s_t, a_t)$ (a pair of sampled state, action), $\zeta(x_t)=\alpha_t(s_t, a_t)$ ($\alpha_t$ is the step size) and $\Delta_t(x) = Q_t(s_t, a_t) - Q^*(s_t, a_t)$. In this case, maximum norm of $\Delta_t$ is:

$$
\|\Delta_t\| = \max_s\max_a |Q_t(s, a) - Q^*(s, a)|
$$

And they go on to map the assumptions of Lemma 1 to the setting of the Expected Sarsa algorithm. ($\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ are finite, the sum of learning rates is unbounded but its square is bounded, the policy is greedy in the limit with infinite exploration and the reward function is bounded.)

### My question (the confusing step)

The authors state that they can derive $F_t$ (which is the only missing step to use Lemma 1) as follows:

$$
F_t = \frac{(\Delta_{t+1}-(1-\zeta_t(x_t))\Delta_t(x_t)}{\zeta_t(x_t)}
    = \frac{\left(\Delta_{t+1}-(1-\alpha_t)\Delta_t\right)}{\alpha_t}
$$

The confusing step is that they conclude:

$$
F_t = r_t + \gamma\sum_a\pi_t(s_{t+1}, a)Q_t(s_{t+1}, a)-Q^*(s_t, a_t)
$$

How did the authors get to that equality? They mention that "all the values are taken over the state action pair $(s_t, a_t)$, except when specified differently". I don't see any explicit mention of a different state-action pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out. The key here is to use the Expected Sarsa update:

$$
Q(s_t, a_t)\leftarrow Q(s_t, a_t) + \alpha[r_{t+1}+\gamma\sum_a\pi(s_{t+1},a)-Q(s_t, a_t)]
$$

Notice that we can define this update as $Q_{t+1}$, and this is key to the proof. For simplicity, let us define the target of the Expected Sarsa update as

$$
\tau_{t+1}=r_{t+1}+\gamma\sum_a\pi(s_{t+1}, a)Q(s_{t+1}, a)
$$

Now, we can expand the confusing step as follows:

$$
F_t = \frac{(\Delta_{t+1}-(1-\alpha_t)\Delta_t}{\alpha_t} = \frac{Q_{t+1}(s_t, a_t)-Q^*(s_t, a_t) - (1-\alpha_t)(Q_t(s_t, a_t)-Q*(s_t, a_t))}{\alpha_t} =\\
= \frac{Q_{t+1}(s_t,a_t)-Q_t(s_t,a_t)+\alpha_t(Q_t(s_t,a_t)-Q^*(s_t,a_t)}{\alpha_t}
$$

Now, substituting $Q_{t+1}(s_t, a_t)$ by the Expected Sarsa update:

$$
F_t = \frac{Q_t(s_t,a_t)+\alpha[\tau_{t+1}-Q(s_t, a_t)]-Q_t(s_t,a_t)+\alpha_t(Q_t(s_t,a_t)-Q^*(s_t,a_t))}{\alpha_t} = \\
= \tau_{t+1}-Q^*(s_t,a_t)
$$

Which gives us

$$
F_t = r_{t+1}+\gamma\sum_a\pi_t(s_{t+1}, a_t)Q_t(s_{t+1}, a_t) - Q^*(s_t, a_t)
$$

As you might have noticed, this expansion uses $r_{t+1}$ instead of $r_t$, as in the proof. I'm assuming that's a typo (since they dropped the $t$ subscript in the action $a$ as well), since the convention used in the paper is that the immediate reward of action $a_t$ on state $s_t$ is represented by $r_{t+1}$.